# Publish Issue in the Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

I am using Umbraco 4.6.2 version of the Umbraco.

Despite of publishing new code from Umbraco Admin Panel, We are not able to view the modified pages. We need to republish the page then only the change is visible on the site. We need to republish on the different environment.

Eg: if i am publishing from my machine i can see that in the menu. but i can't get the same in my colleague machine. When i am login with admin in my colleague machine and publish the code then i can see the Change on the site. then, if i open the site from my mobile i can't see the change.

So, the problem is i need to publish that on every machine. is there any solution of this.

Help me please....

Answer (score 1):

Hi had issue close to this one.
My problem was solved by deleting all items from Recycle-bin. I think if you right click on Recycle Bin and click Empty Recycle Bin, the progress bar wont proceed. If so your umbraco database is dirty. which means in UmbracoNode table there are some nodes that have been deleted but their subnodes are not marked as "trashed" or something like this.

Run following Query against your database to delete all dirty nodes from UmbracoNode table and all their dependencies.

```
DECLARE @nodeId int
SET @nodeId = 0

SELECT id INTO #nodes FROM umbracoNode WHERE (path like '%-20%' AND id != -20 AND @nodeId = 0) OR (id = @nodeId)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #nodes
DELETE FROM umbracoUser2NodeNotify WHERE nodeId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM umbracoUser2NodePermission WHERE nodeId IN (SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM umbracoRelation WHERE parentId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM umbracoRelation WHERE childId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM cmsTagRelationship WHERE nodeId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM umbracoDomains WHERE domainRootStructureID IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM cmsDocument WHERE NodeId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM cmsPropertyData WHERE contentNodeId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM cmsPreviewXml WHERE nodeId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM cmsContentVersion WHERE ContentId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM cmsContentXml WHERE nodeID IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)
DELETE FROM cmsContent WHERE NodeId IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)

DELETE FROM umbracoNode WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM #nodes)

DROP TABLE #nodes
```

then republish all your contents both from "Republish Entire Site" and Right click on sites main node and right click and choose Publish and check both checkboxes.